# Crontab to restart service

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cron, service

I am running a web server on an AWS EC2 micro instance. The instance has ~630MB of RAM. With time, I have several httpd processes and very little free RAM. When I restart the httpd service, I end up freeing about 350MB of RAM.

I thought of having this automated every 12 hours using a cron job under root. My script includes code as

```
service httpd restart
service mysqld restart
ps aux
free -m
```

This is the first time I am attempting cron scripts.

I receive an email with the expected output for `ps aux` and `free -m`, but

```
./scriptName.sh: line 1: service: command not found
./scriptName.sh: line 2: service: command not found
```

for the restarts commands.

The script did run as root. I am afraid that using `sudo` may cause the script to hang. The relevant lines from the output of `ps` -

```
root     14664  0.0  0.2 142200  1720 ?        S    22:41   0:00 CROND
root     14665  0.0  0.2   9296  1236 ?        Ss   22:41   0:00 /bin/sh -c ./scriptName.sh
smmsp    14667  0.0  0.6  76020  4244 ?        R    22:41   0:00 /usr/sbin/sendmail -FCronDaemon -i -odi -oem -oi -t -f root
root     14669  0.0  0.1  11244  1008 ?        R    22:41   0:00 ps aux
```

What is the right thing to do to have a successful restart of services?

Is it even advisable to do something like this?

Output of `free -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           596        573         23          0          8         71
-/+ buffers/cache:        493        103
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: Since your using apache, and probably using mpm_prefork, then why not set `MaxRequestsPerChild`, so child processes are terminated after handling a certain number of requests?  Next, is re-starting really the right answer?  Restarting your services like mysql because it uses memory is a bad idea.  The whole point of it using memory, is so that it can give you answers faster.  If it is using too much, then adjust the settings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The primary problem is that there is no proper `$PATH` defined in the run environment of cron, so you need to use the full path to `service` for this to work.

You can find out this path with the command `which service`, which should print something like  `/usr/sbin/service`.

The secondary problem: I wouldn't do that, just blindly restarting services on a production system is never a good idea. Do you have an actual memory/performance problem or might it be that your RAM is just used up by buffers and the like (see http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)?

Please add the output of `free -m` after a few hours to your question.

Comment: Added the o/p of `free -m`.

Answer (score 3):

It might be better to look at something like Monit instead of trying to do a homebrew cron script.

Here's the example config for Apache:

http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples#apache

You should be able to do something like:

`if totalmem > 300 MB for 2 cycles then alert`

in the Apache block.

Monit should be in one of the RPM repositories.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Look into tuning Apache first of all. Then, research Linux memory management. You WANT your server using the ram, otherwise why do you have it?

Comment: I think I'll try to tune apache. My RAM is highly limited and would like to have some free RAM for some process popping up.

Comment: I run several sites on a tiny instance that are receiving a LOT of hits. Read this: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ your ram will be there for processes unless your sites are being hammered. NINJA EDIT: You WANT Apache using that ram, otherwise your sites will load slowly. If something needs the ram and you're not getting a bunch of traffic, the system will 'release' it for that process to use.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want free RAM?  free ram is wasted RAM.  Either you are miscalculating the amount of ram free by not counting cache memory as free ram (see [linuxatemyram.com](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)) or you should be tuning your apache for fewer MaxClients so that apache will us less memory.

Comment: I have just 630 MB RAM. I would like to have some free for some eventuality and not run out of it 100%.

Comment: @LordLoh. - you need to learn about how linux uses RAM. Stew is right, you **don't** really want any free ram. Don't try and out-smart the linux kernel when it comes to memory management. Just let the system run and do its thing.

Comment: @LordLoh.how are you determining the amount of free RAM?

Comment: @stew - by running `free -m`.

Comment: and are you properly discounting the RAM being used as cache?  Your output of free -m actually shows that you actually have 15% or so of you RAM free?